# Upgrade from MVC 2. 0 to MVC 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, migration

I am using "ASP.NET MVC 3 Application Upgrader" application available to download.

The moment I direct this EXE to perform action on my sln, which has MVC 2.0 projects, I am getting the following error:

ERROR: There was an error loading the solution file
ERROR: The project's type and its reference to System.Web.Mvc do not match versions

The project GUID are as follows:

```
    <ProjectGuid>{1026C2EA-F577-479A-B4FF-007F3DB5E347}</ProjectGuid>
<ProjectTypeGuids>{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

*Please note that I have got more than one project in this solution file.*

Comment: Is there any chance you were using a CTP or other pre-RTM package for Asp.NET MVC 2?

Comment: @jlnorsworthy no mate. I don't think I have been using CTP or so. I always like to go in stable ground :-) That is why I am moving to MVC 4.0 now! :))